# Using `onClick` for touch taps fails if a user moves their finger slightly during the button press

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

I have a touch display that uses React. I have several buttons that use the `onClick` event, looking something like:

```js
<button onClick={() => console.log('onClick')}>Hello!</button>
```

When I was observing users using this interface on a touch screen, I noticed that sometimes the taps did not register correctly. Users would get frustrated and mash the button harder, which made it register clicks even less.

Testing this using:

```js
['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend', 'touchcancel'].forEach((x) => window.addEventListener(x, () => console.log(x)))
```

I found that users were moving their fingers very slightly, enough to trigger a `touchmove` event. This `touchmove` event effectively cancels the clicks, as clicks require `touchstart` and `touchend` consecutively, without `touchmove`. I tried disabling the `touchmove` event using

```js
window.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation()}, {passive: false})
```

...but that didn't really affect much.

I could refactor my code to use `onTouchEnd` and `onMouseUp` but this seems cumbersome. Is there a way that I can better handle `onClick` events for touch devices? Is there a way of overriding the behavior of `onClick` so it'll ignore `touchmove` events?

---

Edit: Here's an example with screencast of Chrome's dev tools:

Screencast: https://imgur.com/qMZFdxl

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwoact9u/2/

It only seems to occur in Chrome but not Firefox. I'm not sure about other browsers.

Comment: This seems like something that should be configured in the device's settings, perhaps Accessibility, to control their sensitivity to movement.

Comment: @Barmar I've checked the accessibility settings on several phones but this seems to be the standard behavior. It's also replicable in the Chrome dev tools' mobile device mode: https://jsfiddle.net/u74Lkfpj/1/ (note that it does not seem to occur on Firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of `WeakMap` to provide auto cleanup and `pointerevent` to provide as much cross compatibility as possible.

- Register the element on a weakmap with the action(s) you want to fire.
- Register a handler on the outermost parent to fire the event if any element was found on the WeakMap. If the device does cancel the `pointerup`event, then use `touchend` as a backup. This should work both in desktop and any touch device.

The throttling of the action, if you need, is left to you. I deliberately left  the solution generic, so people who do not use any framework can use it too.

Bonus: you can use `setTimeout` or other methods within `beginClick` or use `pointerleave` to set `currentRef` to null and thus "expiring" the event after a reasonable delay or if the pointer goes out of boundaries.

PS: Can confirm that this works on mobile stackoverflow, but due to the way code editor works, a script error is thrown first, then on the immediate following touchend, the action is correctly fired.

```js
/*
WeakMap holds weak ref to elements as keys and functions registered on them via `init` as values. If `Element.remove` or `ParentElement.removeChild` is called, they are auto removed via GC. 
The `currentRef`holds the ref to the last element with pointerdown fired on them, which is cleaned up later if any associated action fires.
*/
const wk = new WeakMap(),
      currentRef = {value: null};

document.body.setAttribute("draggable", false);

//desktop or touch, do not care which one fires first
document.body.onpointerup = document.body.ontouchend =  function(e){
  wk.get(currentRef.value)?.(e)
}

//register the element active
function beginClick(e) {
  currentRef.value = e.currentTarget;
  e.currentTarget.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

//fire the action and set currentRef to null
function action(f, el, ...args){
  return wk.set(el, function(e) {
    f.apply(el,[e, ...args]);
    el.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
    currentRef.value = null;
  }).get(el);
}

//initiate everthing
function init(el, f, ...args){
  el.onpointerdown = beginClick;
  action(f, el, ...args);
}

//register the event on the element of choice
init(
  document.getElementById("dabutton"), 
  function(e, arg1){
    console.log(
    "Got a click on: ", this.id, 
    "Pointer ID is: ", e.pointerId,
    "arg1 is: ", JSON.stringify(arg1)
    );
  },
  {haha:"hoho"}
)
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<button id="dabutton">HEY HEY HEY</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there's only one or two buttons , then you can manage variable for like

```
let confirmClick = false
```

and in button

```
onTouchMove={() => confirmClick = true;}
onTouchEnd={() => {
if(confirmClick){
confirmClcik = false;
// do your work here
}
}}
```

make confirm click on touch move instead of touch start so that in normal flow (without touchmove) function not call twice. this way you get both case covered and good to go.